# Creating unique object instance variables

Tags: java, json, gson

Original code from [here](http://www.javabeat.net/parsing-json-using-java-and-gson-library/).
Looking at the code below (ignoring import statements):

```
public class JsonTest2 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonReader reader = null;

    try {
    reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
        FileInputStream("./twitterUser.json")));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JsonArray userArray = jsonParser.parse(reader).getAsJsonArray();

    List<TwitterUser> twitterUsers = new ArrayList<TwitterUser>();
    //For each element in the JSON array, create a new TwitterUser
    //and populate with the json data:
    for ( JsonElement aUser : userArray ) { 
        TwitterUser aTwitterUser = 
            gson.fromJson(aUser, TwitterUser.class);
        twitterUsers.add(aTwitterUser);
    }
    //For each new TwitterUser that was created, print them out:
    for ( TwitterUser tUser : twitterUsers) {
        System.out.println(tUser);
    }
  }
}
```

The array `List twitterUsers = new ArrayList();` gets created and contains two instances of `TwitterUser`.

How do I reference each instance individually (what is their variable name)? If this is not possible e.g. you can only use `TwitterUser[0]`, how can I use JSON to create say five objects each with individual variable names?
Also a bit of explaining-around the subject is probably needed...

Comment: In response to "what is their variable name", the loose answer is "whatever you want" - but please refer to [Oracle's tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List` is not an array. An `ArrayList` is a `List` that is backed by an array (that you can't access directly). Instead you use the `List` interface to

1. [`List.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) which *Returns the element at the specified position in this list.*
2. Use the [`List.iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) to iterate the `List`, perhaps indirectly with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

So, for the first case

```
TwitterUser tu = twitterUsers.get(0); // <-- get the first TwitterUser
                                      //     in the List.
```

or for the second

```
for (TwitterUser tu : twitterUsers) {
  // do something with each TwitterUser in tu
}
```

Comment: Your first case is what I was looking for.
But it requires manually coming-up with a name for the instance variable.
If only there was a way to programmatically create instance variables like `TwitterUser1`, `TwitterUser2` etc.

Comment: And how would you then access them? *Programmatically* like an array? There is `Map` which can give you key value pairs.

Comment: lol, yeah point taken. I'm probably thinking about doing something that entirely doesn't need to be done!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I reference each instance individually

As `twitterUsers[0]` and `twitterUsers[1]`.

> (what is their variable name)?

They aren't variables, and they don't have names.

> If this is not possible e.g. you can only use TwitterUser[0], how can I use JSON to create say five objects each with individual variable names?

You can't.  Variable names things that you write in your source code ... before it is compiled.  A library class (such as the JSON library you are using) can only do things at runtime ... after the source code is compiled.

But if you *really* want different variables, then it is easy to write your code to do this, provided you know *exactly* how many variables are required; e.g.

```
TwitterUser userOne = twitterUsers[0];
TwitterUser userTwo = twitterUsers[1];
```

Obviously, this is hard-wiring the assumption that there are (at least) two elements in the JSON array you will be receiving.

---

Is this a good idea?  Probably not:

- It doesn't scale.
- If the number of variables to be populated is not constant, your code gets rather complicated and fragile.  (You can initialize them to `null`, but you then have to deal with possible nulls each time you use the variables!)
- You are hard-wiring assumptions that *typically* shouldn't be hard-wired.  (At a minimum you should check that the number of elements in the JSON array matches your expectations ... and treat an incorrect assumption as an error!)
- But in some circumstances, it could make the code easier to read; e.g. if the named variables (`userOne` and `userTwo`) are going to be used extensively, or they have more descriptive names.

---

What about using a Map instead of variables?  It does scale (sort of) but you still have problems when the number of entries in the array is variable.  And the code is more complicated.